# One click event with multiple triggers to make content slide up and down

Tags: javascript, jquery, slidetoggle, slidedown

I am here again for another question I need help in but can't seem to find a solution to. I have this feature utilizing `slideDown()` and `slideUp()`, which you can view [here](https://jsfiddle.net/h7emw7of/1/).

The issue here is I've tried `slideToggle()` but I'm looking to collapse one content area when another trigger link is clicked and `slideToggle()` keeps it open unless you click on the same trigger link again to close it.

```
var panel = $('.panel').hide();

$('.toggle').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var loc = this.id; //this grabs the name of the location  

  if ($('.panel').hasClass('clicked')) {
    $('.panel.clicked').removeClass('clicked');
    $('.panel').slideUp();
  }

  $('.panel.' + loc).addClass('clicked');
  $('.panel.' + loc).slideDown();
});
```

Currently the code above works but if you were to click on [TMC and click on TMC again to close it, it slides up and slides down again](https://jsfiddle.net/h7emw7of/1/). `SlideToggle` will just open all of them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check to see if the panel was previously open before sliding it down. You can do this by selecting the panel corresponding to the clicked `.toggle` element and checking whether it has a class of `clicked`. Aside from that, I simplified your code a little as well.

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/2z10js2x/)

```
$('.toggle').click(function(event) {
  var id = this.id,
      wasOpen = $(this).closest('.expand').next('.panel').hasClass('clicked');

  event.preventDefault();
  $('.panel').removeClass('clicked').slideUp();

  if (!wasOpen) {
    $('.panel.' + id).addClass('clicked').slideDown();
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! It works. I'm still learning Javascript so the wasopen threw me off until I realized it's a variable.

Comment: @ruthless It told me to wait awhile, but I did.

Answer (score 0):

Jose you just need to add a return statement to jump out of the stack. Like this:

if ($('.panel').hasClass('clicked')) {

```
$('.panel.clicked').removeClass('clicked');
$('.panel').slideUp();
return; //new code here
```

}

There's also a jquery UI library that has mastered this functionality: https://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Comment: Click one panel then click another panel without closing the first, it will close the first panel without opening the new one with this code.

Comment: Thanks, I've considered using the accordion UI but I'm limited to what libraries I can add :/

Comment: I prefer Josh's implementation to mine :)

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is add an else so that `slideUp()` and `slideDown()` don't run right after each other. If you read code you are closing it then opening it after. No matter if you have just closed it.

```
else{

    $('.panel.' + loc).addClass('clicked');
    $('.panel.' + loc).slideDown();
}
```